# jQuery ':tabbable' selector with .children()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm attempting to write a couple events that respond to keypresses on 'document' to always handle correct tabbing functionality within a modal window, aka always keeping tab focus inside the modal.

I have a working jsFiddle but this assumes that all tabbable elements are direct children of the modal container using

```
var $modalTabElements = $(modalID +">:tabbable");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qodyp3jn/12/

Here is the same demo, except now the inputs in the modal are nested in another div 
the only difference here is the selector

```
var $modalTabElements = $(modalID).children(":tabbable");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qodyp3jn/13/

Does the ':tabbable' selector not work with the .children() method, or is there something else I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) returns only direct children. You want to [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) all tabbable descendants:

```
var $modalTabElements = $(modalID).find(":tabbable");
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qodyp3jn/15/)